# Asking for sign up with Credit Card, Should you show card info after sign up info?

Tags: usability, login, registration

I'm creating a sign up page for a user to purchase a service. There is no free trial so a credit card is necessary on sign up. I think having email, name, password plus credit card might be a little bit of a put off. I thought maybe once you type in your name and email and hit sign up the billing form could show up underneath or slide in. Is this misleading and a put off in itself? Should it all just be on the page right away?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Should it be on one page?**

Yes, but I would now show it / have those be visible. Recommendation is to either reveal those via AJAX or other means.

**Other important things to consider:**

Asking for a CC information upfront will cause a higher drop off rate. If you do everything on a single page / tab it would be more challenging for you to identify how many people dropped off because of the CC information you ask for upfront.

Most successful forms (from conversion stand point) only have one field. The more fields you add, the lower your conversion rate will be.

Now, if you are interested in learning statistics at that level. I would suggest asking for Name and Email only upfront (this will give you total number of "leads") then have a CTA to reveal CC fields on the same page. The number of people who click on the first CTA can be compared to the number of people clicking on the last CTA allowing you to validate if that drop off rate is low or extremely high.

Comment: I also thought to 'reveal' it once the first step is complete by showing it on the same page. I also agree all of that at once might create friction for the user. I think having a 'next > billing' like suggested below, with the email sign up is a good way to avoid being misleading.

Comment: You might also consider putting a disclaimer somewhere that lets the user know they will need their credit card at some point in the near future. Filling out an impersonal form, then suddenly being prompted to enter credit card info could be a recipe for instant navigation far away from the page.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a fairly simple process so I would opt for a single page. I think its best to be "upfront" with the user and show everything unless something is a distraction (which in this case does not seem so since it's a required part of the process). If you do want to split this into two steps, a step tracker or a primary call to action that says "Next: Billing Info" can help to manage expectations.

Comment: I think that's a great idea, to add 'next: billing' somewhere so at least they know that's part of the process.